# jQuery Datatables update one existing row while adding a new row above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I have this table I am work with using datatables.js to help me make it a bit functional. That said I have come across the need to have 6 initially rendered rows in this table that are for the most part forever to remain intact, and in there positions with one exception well 3, but only one currently matters as I think if I can tackle this one problem the others that are similar down the road should be fairly easy to mimic. Anyway, that exception to the rule is the very last row of the 6 static rows is to remain at the bottom always. With that I need to append a row above the last row. Meaning row 6 will be the new 7 and the new row will be row 6.

My table has sorting off from the client side respect, but does retain a sort order through what will be a hidden column. So with that I need to adjust that columns index of sorting every time something runs through it. Which I can do with a first run of the function Ive come up with thus far, but if I trigger that function again after its run, the order goes a bit crazy. So that said here is my datatables code:

```
var oTable = $('#manager').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sScrollY": "300px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc']],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sInfo": 'Tasks: _END_',
            "sEmptyTable": "No Job/Task Sources to display currently.",
            "sInfoEmpty": "No Job/Task(s)."
        },
        "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": true, "bVisible": true},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"5%", "sClass":"center"},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"85%"},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"10%"},
           ]
    });
```

Here is the function Ive come up with thus far..

```
function newTaskData()
{
    var lastTR = taskmanagerTable.fnGetData($('.static:last').get(0));
    var currLast = parseInt(lastTR[0]);
    var newLast = parseInt(lastTR[0])+1;
    alert([newLast, currLast])

    taskmanagerTable.fnUpdate(newLast, currLast, 0);
    taskmanagerTable.fnAddData([currLast, 'checkbox', 'data source', 'E R D']);
    taskmanagerTable.fnDraw();
}
```

And here is a couple screen caps of first run vs multiple runs

[image: First Run]
[image: Multiple Runs]

I don't even know how to explain what the problem is, so hopefully the images help

Comment: Should have mentioned that that first run image (left) is the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just use `fnDeleteRow` on the last row (the checkbox), add your new record, and re-add the checkbox.

Your issue is occurring because you're copying the entire row object, including the index, which is why you end up with two 6s in your screenshot.

Comment: But is there no method to update that index, from a visual perspective I can get it to index respectively, but the datatable does not retain or reflect that upon forcing a sort via `fnSort()` so I see what the issue is now, and your reference helps reenforce the notion. Deleting the one row and readding it may be an option, but at the same time, not so much. As eventually the other static rows will need data appended before/after them in a sense to group them over time which means similar logic will apply to them as well in time.